# Send Nested JSON Object without Escape Character

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to send a nested JSONObject to a server using JSONObjectRequest.  The server is expecting a JSONObject in the form of:

```
{  
   "commit":"Sign In",
   "user":{  
      "login":"my username",
      "password":"mypassword"
   }
}
```

but currently my program is sending through the following (`jsonObject.tostring()`)

```
{  
   "commit":"Sign In",
   "user":"   {  
      \"login\”:\”myusername\”,
      \”password\”:\”mypassword\”
   }   ”
}
```

The JSONObjects are made by:

```
final JSONObject loginRequestJSONObject = new JSONObject();
final JSONObject userJSONObject = new JSONObject();
userJSONObject.put("login", "myuser");
userJSONObject.put("password", "mypass");

loginRequestJSONObject.put("user", userJSONObject);
loginRequestJSONObject.put("commit", "Sign In");
Map<String, String> paramsForJSON = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramsForJSON.put("user", userJSONObject.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "");
paramsForJSON.put("commit", "Sign In");
JSONObject objectToSend =  new JSONObject(paramsForJSON);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, objectToSend,...)
```

How can I send a JSONObject in the form above?

Comment: Which server are u using ? Like .net or php ?

Comment: It's using ruby on rails

Comment: @BabulPatel what's the relevance of the server?

Comment: Use Gson for creating Json string from a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error:

```
paramsForJSON.put("user", userJSONObject.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", ""));
```

You've turned the user into a `String` you don't need to, just do this:

```
loginRequestJSONObject.put("user", userJSONObject);
```

Though you've already done this, you've actually got the correct lines in there, this is all you need:

```
final JSONObject loginRequestJSONObject = new JSONObject();
final JSONObject userJSONObject = new JSONObject();
userJSONObject.put("login", "myuser");
userJSONObject.put("password", "mypass");

loginRequestJSONObject.put("user", userJSONObject);
loginRequestJSONObject.put("commit", "Sign In");

JSONObject objectToSend = loginRequestJSONObject;
```

Comment: So should I change the paramsForJSON map into a Map<String, JSONObject>, and give that to the JsonObjectRequest?

Comment: You know I just noticed you already have some correct lines, the map is not needed.

Comment: A `JSONObject` is already a map in effect, that's why it's so easy to create one if you have a map. So skip the middle man and just work with `JSONObject`s.

Comment: I would also recommend you look at [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) though. I personally use this rather than `JSONObject`.